# listitem that breaks starts again under bullet

Tags: html, css

Like this:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

---

Comment: Can't reproduce this, please show your HTML

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to ensure your `<li>` elements are within an unordered list `<ul>` block

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set your `list-style-position` to "inside" instead of using the default "outside"

Comment: He'd want `outside`, not `inside`.